# Rails - how to render an action as JS without using ":remote => true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In the view, I have a link that I call as AJAX:

```
= link_to "Show post", post, :remote => true
```

and action in the controller:

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

When I click this link, the request is called as AJAX and a popup window with the respective content is displayed. Also, the wanted address is added to the URL (for example `web.com/posts/6`).

So far so good.

But now when I try to put to the URL `web.com/posts/6`, I get only an error message saying:

```
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE `posts`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 535ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

I am trying to achieve that when I put the URL `web.com/posts/6` to the browser, then the page will be rendered the same way as if I click on a link with the `:remote => true` option.

How to do that? How to force an action in controller to be rendered as JS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link (basically just add the format `.js` to the end):

```
web.com/posts/6.js
```

This also works with any other kind of format you want (say `json` or `xml`). Just make sure you account for those formats in your controller action.

Comment: Well, this is honestly not a very friendly approach sharing a link with `.js` in the end

Comment: I agree it doesn't look pretty, but I think it is most friendly.  As far as I know, it's the only one. There maybe another way that you can tweak in the controller, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your input, I'm keep searching and will post it if I find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
= link_to "Show post", post, :remote => true
```

By

```
= link_to "Show post", post, :remote => true, :format => 'js'
```

*Warning*

@user984621 is right : this is very strange to get a link with js.

Comment: Strange yes, but nothing wrong with it. This answer doesn't really change anything, since JavaScript automatically adds the format of `js` on anything that has `remote: true` on it. I think he wants a way to allow a direct link (from the browser) to have a format of `js` and this is the only way I know.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm - I am trying to figure out how to render an action as JS when I [manually] put to the URL `web.com/posts/6`. If you put that URL to the browser, it will be rendered as HTML. But I am trying to force the controller to render this action as JS.

Comment: Well I guess that would work too. Just depends on which you think looks nicer.